# Time needed to get a Vietnamese motorcycle license and riding into Laos and Cambodia?

Tags: thailand, vietnam, motorcycles, cambodia, laos

I have a United States driver's license with a motorcycle endorsement, the associated IDP, and I have been riding motorcycles for years. I've also previously rented motorbikes in Thailand and China for extended periods of time.

I want to buy a typical 100-150cc motorbike in Hanoi and ride into Laos and Cambodia and back into Vietnam.

- I want to do everything legally and have my travel insurance cover me in case something happens.
- It's my understanding that Vietnam does not accept IDPs, so I would need to get an actual Vietnamese motorbike license.

Soooo...

- Considering I have a full motorbike license in the USA and the IDP, how quickly can I get a motorbike license in Vietnam?
- Which agency would you recommend I go with to help me get this license, and how long would it take to get?
- Am I able to legally cross into and ride in Laos and Cambodia with either a Vietnamese license or an American license with IDP?
- Is there no way to cross into Thailand on a Vietnamese motorbike if the blue card isn't in your name?
- Any recommendations on motorbike models to get? I'd like to avoid the ubiquitous Honda Win since they seem to have a lot of problems.

Comment: As of three years ago when I was there it was illegal for foreigners (non-citizen) to own or even rent vehicles without a driver. We all did, of course. Lonely Planet indicates that foreigners with IDP can now rent cars, though no agency will rent one without a driver.